# re.match (regular expression) in python: matching issue

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match some pattern (in a much bigger program). So my code right now is:

```
line = 'Name toyota;'
mo = re.match(r'(\w+)\s+([\w\s]+);', line)
print mo.group()
```

and this nicely prints: `Name toyota;`

but what if `line` can be anything. Examples:
`line = name SPU123-6CU;` or `line = name SPU123-389-2147656-1;` or `line = name SPU123-389-1213609-0_fuse;` or `line = name SPU123-1/0CN15;` etc etc etc, how to make `mo` universal so irrespective of the string pattern in `line`, how can I have a single `re.match` statement and print out my output?

Comment: Please clarify the question a little better.

Comment: `but what if line can be anything?` Ans `.*`

Comment: If `line` could be anything why even implement regex?

Comment: @hwnd because I need to extract the content after `name` in `line` and use it in the program for something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the string after name.

```
mo = re.match(r'^(\w+)\s+(\S+);', line)
```

OR

```
mo = re.match(r'^(\w+)\s+([^;]*);', line)
```

And get the string you want from group index 2. `[^;]*` negated character class which matches any character but not of `;` zero or more times. `\S+` matches any number of non-space characters.

```
>>> re.match(r'^(\w+)\s+([^;]*);',"name SPU123-389-1213609-0_fuse;").group(2)
'SPU123-389-1213609-0_fuse'
>>> re.match(r'^(\w+)\s+([^;]*);',"name SPU123-1/0CN15;").group(2)
'SPU123-1/0CN15'
>>> re.match(r'^name\s+([^;]*);',"name SPU123-1/0CN15;").group(1)
'SPU123-1/0CN15'
```

Comment: I think this just should do what I am looking for...
but I have a question: if another possibility of `line` is `line = rating.summer.continuous 340;` how can this be handled?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
line ="SPU123-6CU  fgfg"
mo = re.match(r'(?s).*', line)
print mo.group()
```

As has been point out by a few people:

```
line ="SPU123-6CU  fgfg"
print line
```

looks like what you really need

Comment: How about dispensing with the cpu cycles and assume `line` contains what we want?

Comment: `print line`  you mean?

Comment: Yes.  The op's question makes no sense.

Comment: @7stud In examples there are few patterns of `line`, I am trying to write a `re.match` for `line` that can match for any of those patterns. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: @Nikhil Gupta do you have examples of thing it shouldn't match?

Comment: @JBradley there isn't anything that I shouldn't match. I am working with a file that looks like a `JSON` file and `name` is one of the default keys. So `name` is not the only "key" but one of many "keys" of the JSON object

Comment: @JBradley below answers pretty much solves my problem